# How to parse txt file containing a repository of patterns

Tags: tcl

I am new in scripting in TCL, I want to parse a txt file to create a list of patterns based on 2 strings as input.

My file looks like:

```
keyw1: data1
keyw1: data2
keyw1: Arg1
:
:
keyword: Pattern2Extract
{
some_lines
keyw1: Arg1
keyw2: patternP1
{
some_lines
}
keyw2: Arg2
{
some_lines
}

keyw2: patternP2
{
some_lines
}
.
.
some_others blocks of declaration between braces {}
.
.
}

keyword: Pattern2Extract
{
some_lines
keyw1: Arg1
keyw2: Arg2
{
some_lines
}

keyw2: patternP1
{
some_lines
}
keyw2: patternP2
{
some_lines
}

.
.
some_others blocks of declaration between braces {}
.
.
}
```

So, I would like to output 2 list of 'Pattern2Extract'

- `list1`: if Arg1 is found in structure grouped between curly braces {}
- `list2`: if arg1 and arg2 are both in structure grouped between curly braces {}

I have tried `lsearch` and `lindex` and it's working for `list1` but I don't know how to do it for `list2`.

Here is my script:

```
proc inst_nm {inpFile outFile} {
    set chanId [open $inpFile r]
    set data [list]
    while {[gets $chanId line] != -1} {
        lappend data $line
    }
    close $chanId
    foreach dt $data {
            set MasDat [lindex $dt 0]
            set pinDat [lindex $dt 1]
    }   
        set intId [open "./filetoparse.txt" r]
    set instDat [list]
    while {[gets $intId line] != -1} {
        lappend instDat $line
    }
    close $intId
    set writeId [open $outFile a]
    set MasterList [lreplace  [lsearch -all  $instDat *$MasDat*] 0 0]
    foreach elem $MasterList {
        set cellLn   [lindex [split [lindex $instDat $elem ] ":"] 1]
        set instName [lindex [split [lindex $instDat [expr $elem -5]] ":"] 1]
        set PinLn    [lindex [split [lindex $instDat [expr $elem +1]] ":"] 1]
        foreach ele $PinLn {
            if {"$ele"=="$pinDat" } { 
                puts $writeId "$instName $pinDat $cellLn"   
            } else {
                puts $writeId "$instName $ele $cellLn" 
            }
        }
    } 
    close $writeId
}
inst_nm [lindex $::argv 0] [lindex $::argv 1]
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what should be in `list2`. Do you want the immediate keyword-value pair or the whole tree?

Comment: Thanks Jerry for your comment. I want in list2 to regroup list of Pattern2Extact with Arg2 in structure body. because it may happen that arg2 would be not present in stucture between braces{}. please tell me if it's not clear enough. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, could you put the script that you used for list1 in your question? (Edit it and put it at the end) I think that should give a better idea of what you're trying to obtain as output.

Comment: Just Add a comment, in my script Arg1 correspond to $MasDat and Arg2 correspond to $pinDat.

Comment: Ok, I'm not entirely sure what the output should look like for `list2` and I don't understand why your script does certain things but I guess there are things that are inherent to your data, like 1. the first pair of keyword-value is always ignored, probably because it is not between braces, 2. there seems to be only two keyword-value pairs in each part, 3. five lines above the match is where the `instName` is found. Regardless, are you expecting to get the list `Pattern2Extract Arg1 Arg2` as the only result for `list2` for the sample you provided?

Comment: Hi Jerry, for point 1 you're right it is intended because I'm interested by keyword-value pairs into barces.

Comment: Hi Jerry, for point 1 you're right it is intended because I'm interested by keyword-value pairs into barces. and for point 2 each line in my file is like 'key: value'. 3. I have proceed by this way (extracting five lines above) because I didn't know how to get instName based on $MasDat and $pinDat. thanks

Comment: Ok. For `list2`, what is the result you are expecting to see?

Answer (score 0):

It helps to break out the code into another proc. In Tcl the proc must be declared ahead of when you call it.  The data file didn't reflect your parser and also the MasterList might be removing the found item your looking for. Below is your parser broken up with example files that reflect what it's doing.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

proc findPin {MasDat pinDat instDat} {
    # set MasterList to the list of indexes found for *$MastDat*
    set MasterList [lsearch -glob -all  $instDat *$MasDat*]
    set found [list]

    # for each index number in MasterList
    foreach elem $MasterList {

        # n-5 (key: value(instName))
        # n-4
        # n-3
        # n-2
        # n-1
        # n (key: value(cellLn)
        # n+1 (key: value(PinLn)

        set cellLn   [lindex [split [lindex $instDat $elem ] ":"] 1]
        set instName [lindex [split [lindex $instDat [expr $elem -5]] ":"] 1]
        set PinLn    [lindex [split [lindex $instDat [expr $elem +1]] ":"] 1]

        foreach ele $PinLn {
            if {"$ele"=="$pinDat" } { 
                lappend found "$instName $pinDat $cellLn"
            }
        }
    }

    return $found
}

proc inst_nm {inpFile outFile} {

    # geta all lines in filestoparse.txt
    set intId [open "./filetoparse.txt" r]
    set instDat [list]
    while {[gets $intId line] != -1} {
        lappend instDat $line
    }
    close $intId

    set writeId [open $outFile a]

    # Search each line in inpFile
    set chanId [open $inpFile r]
    while {[gets $chanId line] != -1} {
        set MasDat [lindex $line 0]
        set pinDat [lindex $line 1]
        foreach {item} [findPin $MasDat $pinDat $instDat] {
             puts $writeId $item
        }
    }

    close $chanId
    close $writeId
}

inst_nm [lindex $::argv 0] [lindex $::argv 1]
```

filetoparse.txt

```
INST_NAME:MyInst
unknown-1
unknown-2
unknown-3
unknown-4
CELL_LN:MyCellLn
PIN_LN:pin1 pin2 pin3 pin4 pin5

unknown...

INST_NAME:TestInst
unknown-1
unknown-2
unknown-3
unknown-4
CELL_LN:TestCell
PIN_LN:test1 test2 test3
```

inputfile.txt

```
MyCellLn pin4
MyCellLn pin25
TestCell test1
TestCell test10
MyCellLn pin3
```

Output:

```
% ./keylist.tcl inputfile.txt keylist_found.txt
% cat keylist_found.txt
MyInst pin4 MyCellLn
TestInst test1 TestCell
MyInst pin3 MyCellLn
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Currently, inpFile could have many lines like :

Comment: Currently, inpFile may have many lines like $MastDat $pinDat and I need to collect instDat corresponding to each pair ($MastDat,$pinDat). in file_to_parse by construction, we know that instName come in fifth line before $MastDat. However, we don't know the position of line conatining $pinDat declaration and this pattern could be present or not into instance section: keyword: Pattern2Extract
{
some_lines
keyw1: Arg1
keyw2: patternP1
{
some_lines
}
keyw2: Arg2
{
some_lines
}

keyw2: patternP2
{
some_lines
}
.
.
some_others blocks of declaration between braces {}
.
.
}

Answer (score 0):

Currently, inpFile may have many lines like $MastDat $pinDat and I need to collect instDat corresponding to each pair ($MastDat,$pinDat). 
in file_to_parse by construction, we know that instName come in fifth line before $MastDat. However, we don't know the position of line conatining $pinDat declaration and this pattern could be present or not into instance section:

```
keyword: Pattern2Extract { some_lines keyw1: Arg1 keyw2: patternP1 { some_lines } keyw2: Arg2 { some_lines } keyw2: patternP2 { some_lines } . . some_others blocks of declaration between braces {} . . }
```

so, in list2 we should get all insName in where $pinDat is found
Thank you for your help

Comment: Ok, but what should be the output here? Only the insName, meaning `Pattern2Extract`? I don't think so and I don't know what it should be. If you can provide sample of inputs with the outputs that should come with it, it would be easier to help you since it gives something to work and try different things on.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm interested just by printing '$instName' for each pair line from inpFile '$cellLn $pinDat'

filetoparse.txt:

```
    INST_NAME:Inst1
    {
    4 unknown lines
    CELL_LN: Cell1
    other unkown lines
    PIN_LN:pin1 
    unkown
    PIN_LN:pin5
    unknown...
    }

    INST_NAME:Inst2
    {
    4 unknown lines
    CELL_LN: Cell1
    other unkown lines
    PIN_LN:pin3
    unkown
    PIN_LN:pin5
    unknown...
    }

    INST_NAME:Inst3
    {
    4 unknown lines
    CELL_LN: Cell2
    other unkown lines
    PIN_LN:pin2
    unkown
    PIN_LN:pin4
    unknown...
    }

INST_NAME:Inst4
    {
    4 unknown lines
    CELL_LN: Cell2
    other unkown lines
    PIN_LN:pin5
    unkown
    PIN_LN:pin2
    unknown...
    }
```

inpFile.txt

```
cell1 pin1
cell2 pin2
```

So, I want in OutputFile have something like:

```
- for cell1 pin1:
list1: {Inst1 Inst2}
list2: {Inst1}

- for cell2 pin2:
list1: {Inst3 Inst4}
list2: {Inst3 Inst4}
```

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Is there any way you can post a snapshot of the real data structure?  I'm not sure that we're getting everything in the pseudo data.